# Конветирую класс java в kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Конвертирую класс из java в kotlin, при условии, что класс рабочий

```
public class CurrentActivityUtil {
Activity currentActivity;

public Activity getActivityInstance() {
    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Collection<Activity> resumedActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
            for (Activity act : resumedActivity) {
                currentActivity = act;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return currentActivity;
}
}
```

Конвертирую hotkey'ем `ctrl+alt+shift+K` студия предлагает мне следующий вариант кода:

```
class CurrentActivityUtil {
internal var currentActivity: Activity

val activityInstance: Activity
    get() {
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {
            val resumedActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED)
            for (act in resumedActivity) {
                currentActivity = act
                break
            }
        }
        return currentActivity
    }
}
```

И сразу же подчеркивает `internal var currentActivity: Activity`
  - property must be initialized or be abstract , пробую сделать его просто `val currentActivity: Activity`
 но сразу же подчеркивается строка `val currentActivity: Activity`
  - val cannot be reassigned.

Comment: добавьте к ней lateinit, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Kotlin переменная не может принимать значение NULL, если вы прямо этого не указали.

Вариантов у вас три:

1. Все таки задать переменной значение при ее декларации.
2. Использовать [lateinit](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) - это, как бы, обещание, что вы ее инициализируете раньше, чем попытаетесь первый раз использовать. Любые NPE будут на вашей совести.
3. Определить ее как NULLABLE, таким образом: `internal var currentActivity: Activity?`. Знак вопроса после имени класса.

Ну и еще один момент. Декларация `val` означает, что переменная иммутабельна, т.е. константа и ее можно только читать. Для определения "обычной" переменной используйте `var`

Answer (score 2):

Присоеденюсь к ответу данному [раннее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624728/211117) просто дав готовое решения для вашего класса, как это бы сделал я:

```
class CurrentActivityUtil {
internal var currentActivity: Activity? = null

val activityInstance: Activity?
    get() {
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {
            val resumedActivity = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED)
            for (act in resumedActivity) {
                currentActivity = act
                break
            }
        }
        return currentActivity
    }
}
```

Comment: Все же для хранения activity(вообще скользкий момент), либо ссылок на элементы интерфейса `lateint` выглядит гораздо более гармоничным, кмк.